# Is max_input_time included in max_execution_time?

Tags: apache-2.2, php

Example:

```
max_input_time 600
max_execution_time 30
```

Question: Will be my PHP script force to terminate if upload of file(s) from HTML form will take let's say 200 seconds? I'm assuming that execution of the script will not take longer than 30 seconds.

To be more precise: In infrastructure with apache + php: When will PHP start counting max_input_time and when max_exectuion_time?

Comment: I'm almost sure it won't. But the documentation is not really clear on this and the internet is full of different answers on this topic. So I want to make it clear. Basically I need to be sure that the client is able to send very large file via HTML form. And in the same time that if the script is not well written it will be terminated in reasonable time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The maximum execution time is not affected by system calls, stream
>   operations etc.

so , if I work with stream operation that might be taking long a couple of hours, what shall I do ?
Do i need to increase max_input_time in php.ini ? is there a function to increase max_input_time programmatically set_time_limit()?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time

The maximum execution time is not affected by system calls, stream operations etc. Please see the set_time_limit() function for more details.

Comment: This is exactly what I've asked for. There are three ways of how PHP counts time for max_input_time and max_execution_time. 1) Both starts with the beginning of script execution 2) Server receives first bytes of HTTP request and the max_input_time starts counting. When whole HTTP request is at the server and desired script starts execution the max_exectuion_time starts counting. 3) Both starts with the first byte of HTTP request.